# MySQL Get Range of Serial Numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have difficulty to retrieve range of serial numbers in my database due to improper database design.

I've got data as below :-

1. XY100001 - XY101000 | User_A ---> 1000 data
2. XY101001 - XY102000 | User_B ---> 1000 data
3. XY102001 - XY102500 | User_C ---> 500 data
4. XY102501 - XY103000 | User_A ---> 1000 data

and the data will be store in database as below :-

```
| 1    | User_A | XY100001 | DateTime |
| 2    | User_A | XY100002 | DateTime |
..
| 1000 | User_A | XY101000 | DateTime |
| 1001 | User_B | XY101001 | DateTime |
| 1002 | User_B | XY101002 | DateTime |
..
| 2000 | User_B | XY102000 | DateTime |
| 2001 | User_C | XY102001 | DateTime |
| 2002 | User_C | XY102002 | DateTime |
..
| 2500 | User_C | XY102500 | DateTime |
| 2501 | User_A | XY102501 | DateTime |
| 2502 | User_A | XY102502 | DateTime |
..
| 3000 | User_A | XY103000 | DateTime |
```

I tried to select min and max serial number, after that group by DateTime but still cant get correct ranges because each Users will have multiple ranges.

The sample output if I'm using min and max as below :-

```
| User_A | XY100001 | XY103000 |
| User_B | XY101001 | XY102000 |
| User_C | XY102001 | XY102500 |
```

You can see, wrong output for User_A. User_A should have 2 ranges (XY100001-XY101000) and (XY102501-XY103000)

Question is, how can I retrieve back all the ranges?

Any ideas ?

Comment: there are all kinds of [stack overflow posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+missing+date+ranges) about this kind of problem...

Comment: @gloomy.penguin the date is not important because I want to find the range of serial number. how about if there's no date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution

```sql
SELECT user, MIN(sn) range_start, MAX(sn) range_end
  FROM
(
  SELECT user, sn, @r := IF(@g = user, @r, @r + 1) range_num, @g := user
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r := 0, @g := NULL) i
   ORDER BY sn
) q
 GROUP BY user, range_num
```

Sample output:

```
|   USER | RANGE_START | RANGE_END |
|--------|-------------|-----------|
| User_A |    XY100001 |  XY101000 |
| User_A |    XY102501 |  XY103000 |
| User_B |    XY101001 |  XY102000 |
| User_C |    XY102001 |  XY102500 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac7bd/3)** demo

Comment: its working! you iterate each of the serial. thanks peterm. :)